# "One thing to note" or "One thing to be noted"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, phrases

Just stumbled which to use when I was writing something. "One thing to note" seems to be used much more often, but clarifications from experts would be helpful.

Comment: IMO 'one thing to note' has the connotation of 'this is something you should bring your attention to', whereas  'One thing to be noted' seems to mean more of a literal 'take a note(s) on this thing'. That's just my feeling though no concrete evidence to back it up.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "to be noted" is a passive construction.  Passive construction is more common in English than in other languages.  In technical documentation and user instructions, the passive voice is less specific and harder to understand especially for those people who do not read English as a first language.

Per The Global English Style Guide by John R. Kohl

Comment: These comments seem helpful!  I would also note (ha ha) that "to be noted" sounds more formal -- possibly even a little stuffy.